# Create code snippets in Visual Studio Code on trigger keypress TAB?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is this possible in Visual Studio Code, like in **Atom** and **Sublime Text**, where code snippets can be inserted by pressing the **TAB** key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The language you are using needs to support it though.

The following help page explains both how to use them and how to create your own:

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets

There is a setting:

```
"editor.tabCompletion": true
```

That controls if the Tab key triggers an expansion, it's off by default I believe but you can change it from *File -> Preferences -> Settings.*

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Comment: "editor.tabCompletion": "on" or "off". it doesnt take true false

Answer (score 0):

"editor.tabCompletion": true <-- I often get long loading paused with the editor attempting to figure out what else I could want.

```
"editor.tabCompletion": onlySnippets
```

^ I prefer to keep my typing and tabbing to be reserved for my code snippets and instantly will insert my snippet without any lag ever.